# Using AWS CDK Lazy module in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm creating a wrapper class in Python for the `CfnInstance` class of AWS CDK that could benefit from the `Lazy` module that AWS CDK provides to lazily load values when the AWS CDK app is being synthesized. I would need this to add `UserData` to the EC2 instance.

In the source code for their `Instance` class (similar to mine) I found the following code to add userdata:

```
this.userData = props.userData || imageConfig.userData || UserData.forOperatingSystem(imageConfig.osType);
const userDataToken = Lazy.stringValue({ produce: () => Fn.base64(this.userData.render()) });
const securityGroupsToken = Lazy.listValue({ produce: () => this.securityGroups.map(sg => sg.securityGroupId) });
```

So the `userData` and `securityGroups` get a `Lazy` object assigned, which will render the EC2 UserData and SecurityGroups respectively.

This is done by creating a new object `{produce: () => Fn.base64(this.userData.render()) }`, which is an ad-hoc object with an inline function that renders the user data.

However, this is TypeScript, where these `{}` statements indicate objects. What would be the Python equivalent to implement this?

Comment: The AWS CDK is following up on this question in this issue on Github: https://github.com/aws/jsii/issues/807